# Configure & Compile syslog-ng from source, got: Threads are not supported on this platform

Tags: logs, solaris, services, glibc, syslog-ng

I have configure, gmake, and gmake installed `syslog-ng-3.4.0alpha1` with `eventlog-0.2.12` and other dependencies.

From then output of the `./configure --prefix=/syslog --with-gnu-ld`, I can see that the configure script is passing the compiler option `-pthread` and the linker flag `-lpthread`.

```
 syslog-ng Open Source Edition 3.4.0alpha1 configured
 Compiler options:
  compiler                    : gcc -std=gnu99
  compiler options            : -g -O2 -Wall -pthread  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include   -I/usr/local/include/eventlog       -I$(top_srcdir)/lib/ivykis/lib/include -I$(top_builddir)/lib/ivykis/lib/include -I$(top_srcdir)/lib/ivykis/modules/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
  linker flags                :  -lpthread
  prefix                      : /syslog
  linking mode                : dynamic
  __thread keyword            : no
 Submodules:
  ivykis                      : internal
  libmongo-client             : internal
 Features:
  Debug symbols               : no
  GCC profiling               : no
  Memtrace                    : no
  IPV6 support                : yes
  spoof-source support        : no
  tcp-wrapper support         : no
  Linux capability support    : no
  PCRE support                : no
  Env wrapper support         : no
  systemd support             : no (unit dir: none)
 Modules:
  Module search path          : /syslog/lib/syslog-ng
  Sun STREAMS support (module): yes
  SSL support (module)        : no
  SQL support (module)        : no
  PACCT module (EXPERIMENTAL) : no
  MongoDB destination (module): yes
  JSON support (module)       : parser=no, formatter=no (using no)
  SMTP support (module)       : no
```

Is this the cause of the error? And if so, how do I stop syslog from compiling with these options?

Comment: I've done a bit more digging and it looks like my `glib` was compiled without the `--with-threads=posix` flag. I'm trying to reconfigure now but running into trouble. Can anyone tell me if that sounds like at least the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Three notes:

- you should use a current git snapshot instead of alpha1, as alpha1 crashes on start-up.
- please ask on the [syslog-ng mailing list](https://lists.balabit.hu/mailman/listinfo/syslog-ng), as there are more people to answer your question, including syslog-ng developers.
- even current git needs a patch, see this thread on the mailing list: [3.4 on opensuse factory](https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2012-April/018717.html)